# Frattini subgroup of an abelian group equals to Prime subgroup

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

The prime subgroup $\wp(G)$ of an abelian group (maybe infinite) $G$ is defined as $\wp(G)=\bigcap_{p \in \Pi}pG$ where $\Pi$ is the set of all primes. Is it true that $\wp(G) = \Phi(G)$. Where $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $G$ be an abelian group. We assume nothing about cardinality, rank, torsion etc.

**Lemma**: For any prime $p$, the quotient $G/pG$ is elementary abelian.

*Proof*. Suppose $x+pG\in G/pG$. Then $px\in pG$ so $p(x+pG)=pG$ hence $G/pG$ has exponent $p$; it is a direct sum of cyclic groups $Z_p$ (by Prüfer, Baer IIRC).

**Lemma**. A direct sum $\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I}C_i$ of prime-order cyclic groups has trivial Frattini subgroup.

*Proof*. For each coordinate $i$, let $D_i$ be the subgroup of all elements with $0$ in the $i$th coordinate; this subgroup has prime index and so is maximal; the intersection of all these maximal subgroups would have $0$ in every coordinate then, in which case it is the trivial subgroup.

**Corollary**. $\Phi(G)\le \wp(G)$.

*Proof*. By the previous two lemmas, we know that for every prime $p$, $\Phi(G/pG)=0$, hence by the lattice theorem we may lift the maximal subgroups of $G/pG$ up to maximal subgroups $M$ of $G$ such that $\bigcap M=pG$. Since the intersection of maximal subgroups is contained in $pG$ for every $p$, the corollary follows by intersecting these containments.

**Lemma**. $\wp(G)\le \Phi(G)$.

*Proof*. Suppose contrariwise $g\in\bigcap_ppG$ but $g\not\in M$ for some maximal subgroup $M<G$. Now, if the quotient $G/M$ didn't have prime order, then it would have a nontrivial proper subgroup which would lift (by lattice isomorphism theorem) to a proper subgroup of $G$ strictly containing $M$, an impossibility, so $G/M\cong Z_q$ is cyclic for some prime $q$, and $qg\in M$. Furthermore, $\langle M,g\rangle=G$.

Since $g\in\bigcap_ppG$, there is an $h\in G$ such that $g=qh$. Since $\langle M,g\rangle=G$, we have $h=m+kg$ for some $m\in M$ and $0<k<q$. But then $g=qh=q(m+kg)=qm+k(qg)\in M$ since $qg\in M$, a contradiction. Hence every element of the intersection is in every maximal subgroup.

**Theorem**. $\Phi(G)=\wp(G)$.

*Proof*. Combine the two previous propositions.

**Remark**. This argument is adapted from [*The Frattini subgroup of abelian groups*](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/100391/CzechMathJ_10-1960-1_1.pdf).