# Frattini subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}^n, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory

> Compute the Frattini subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}^n, +)$.
>
> Hint: you may use the fact that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ is $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$, and that the $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$-$e_1$ orbit is the set of vectors $(k_1, \ldots, k_n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that their $\gcd$ is $1$.

Comment: Any idea, insight, background...?

Comment: This is an exercise from Kapovich book "Geometric Group Theory" pag 135.

Comment: I did not understand the hint.

Comment: Then ignore the hint. And start solving the case $n=1$.

Comment: I already did the case n =1. Its the intersection of $p\mathbb{Z}$ where p is prime

Comment: You can give a better answer than that - what precisely is that intersection?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. It is the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$. Knowing that the maxinal subgoups are $p\mathbb{Z}$ where p is prime, we have that the frattine subgroup is $\bigcap_{p,prime} p\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Which elements of $\mathbb Z$ lie in $\bigcap_{\textrm{$p$ prime}} p\mathbb Z$?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe just the zero.

Comment: I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258331/frattini-subgroup-of-an-abelian-group-equals-to-prime-subgroup

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed, as it is simply a question from a book. They've shown some effort in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, the OP stated that she already partially solved the case $n=1$. Indeed, for any prime $p$, there is a maximal subgroup $p\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Now, for any **nonzero** $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is some prime $p$ which does not divide it, namely $m \notin p\mathbb{Z}$, which means that the intersection of all the subgroups $p\mathbb{Z}$ over all primes is the trivial subgroup $\{0\}$.

The subgroups $p\mathbb{Z}$ can be interpreted as the kernel of the reduce-mod-$p$ homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, where every integer is mapped to its minimal residue modulo $p$. Since the image is a group with no non-trivial subgroups, the kernel is a maximal subgroup.

Switching over to the larger group $\mathbb{Z}^n$ we see that similar homomorphisms exist: pick an index $1 \leq i \leq n$ and map $(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n)$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ by looking at $m_i \bmod{p}$. Once again, the kernel is a maximal subgroup. What is the intersection of all of these subgroups?

(I wasn't able to find a way to utilize the hint provided).

Comment: I can't make any sense at all of the hint!

Comment: The not-so-helpful hint suggests the following approach: 1. the Frattini subgroup is characteristic. 2. The characteristic subgroups of $\mathbb Z^n$ are those invariant under $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Z)$. 3. From the hint, $H$ is characteristic iff there is some $d\in \mathbb Z$ such that $H$ consists of exactly those $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ such that $d\mid \gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. In particular, each $H$ is generated as a char. subgp. by an element of the form $D=(d,0,\ldots,0)$. 4. Must have $d=0$, since for any other $d$ there is a $p$ such that $D\notin p\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\cdots\mathbb Z$.